# Simple Prolog program

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to teach myself some Prolog so that I can determine its fitness for solving a problem I have. Essentially the problem is, given a bunch of rules about the interaction between items, determine what items are available, unavailable, selected, and not selected.

But I'm failing at even the most simple parts! I drastically reduced the problem size just to see what I could do. Below is my knowledge base:

```
selected(A) :- implied(A).
implied(B) :- implies(A,B),selected(A).

implied(option_one).
implies(option_one,option_two).
```

And when I query:

```
selected(X).
```

I only get back option_two.

It seems like there is something very basic that I'm not understanding here, but it seems to me that if option_one should also come back in that list (especially since one of the facts is 'implied(option_one)'.

If it matters, I've tried this using P# as well as SWI-Prolog, which give the same result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When u have your first answer `X = option_two` press **;** to get next answer

```
?- selected(X).
X = option_two ;
X = option_one.
```

Or u may use smth like that for showing all matching things:

```
?- selected(X), writeln(X), fail.
option_two
option_one
false.
```

Comment: Wow...I feel REALLY dumb now. I knew that it would only give one result at a time, but for some reason I thought hitting 'Enter' again would have it give me the next result.

Comment: It's ok. Btw, there are really many ways to get what u want. `findall(X, selected(X), List)`

Comment: In recent SWI versions, you can also press SPACE for more solutions.